# How to get data from web to android apps same to same as web?

Tags: android

I want to know how to get description of web blog post same to same as web.
I mean that same to same description from web like after same content there will be image.

I am using  JSON & Picasso, and I just want to get blog post same to same as web blog post with image.

Answer (score 1):

Just load the whole page to Webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("Your URL goes here");
```

if you want to load from HTML

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html_string, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: is it possible from content json (like below) load image

Comment: is it possible from content json (like below) load image

<img class=\"aligncenter wp-image-3179 size-full\" src=\"http:\/\/apkkothon.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/12\/It\u2019s-official-CyanogenMod-Is-Dead-696x392.png\

Comment: webview can load from html. If your json's content contains html, webview can load it

Comment: i don't really get your idea. But webview works just like a web browser. So if Chrome can do anything, so does webview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebView to load the Page.

Comment: is it possible from content json (like below) load image

<img class=\"aligncenter wp-image-3179 size-full\" src=\"http:\/\/apkkothon.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/12\/It\u2019s-official-CyanogenMod-Is-Dead-696x392.png\